# How can I calculate necessary WiFi bandwidth based on # of devices at home?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, bandwidth, mesh-networking

For my home network, I'm trying to set up a Wifi 6 mesh network.

My internet provider subscription gets me 150 Mbps officially, but in practice runs up to about 260 Mbps (max. measured over Wifi 5GHz).

I have about 15 devices that connect ranging from smart devices to smartphones and laptops, TVs and set-top boxes and even a Raspberry Pi. They are on 2 separate floors and the mesh network will connect them using an Ethernet backhaul.

With Wifi 6 the bandwidth (theoretically max. 9.6 Gbps) is to be divided over all of these devices. But I don't think I can just divide the 150 Mbps over my devices and dimension my wifi to just go up to 150 Mbps. There's going to be overhead, areas with lower speeds, concurrency, ...

So my question is: how can I **calculate** the amount of Wifi bandwidth I need (as different Wifi 6 kits offer different max. bandwidths) based on expected bandwidth loss, given the actual 260 Mbps bandwidth from my provider and about 13 Wifi devices, most of which connect on the 5 GHz band?

Ref [closed post](https://superuser.com/questions/1738533/should-i-invest-in-wifi-6-mesh-ax1800-or-ax3000).

Comment: You can't. Number of devices is irrelevant compared to what those devices are doing. An IoT thermometer transferring 50 bytes every half an hour is not the same as a TV downloading 30mbps 4K video or a computer downloading updates at whatever speed the Internet link is capable of.

Comment: But there has to be some kind of heuristic maybe to find out what fork of bandwidths should suffice to cover this? E.g. gaming laptop, work laptop, video conferencing at the same time for about 50 Mbps e.g. how much bandwidth does this require from the Wifi system? Is that 50 Mbps or is it more including overhead etc... Need some sort of metric to see how I could dimension my routers accordingly.

Comment: The "heuristic" is taking a look at all your devices and the people who use them and asking "are they all going to be trying to use as much of the internet as they can at the same time" and "will they mind sharing it". If you have a limit of 150Mbps then a 1900Mbps network is an absolute waste unless all of those machines are ***constantly*** talking amongst themselves to constantly share gigabytes of data every second. To just talk to the internet the maximum network traffic you will reasonably see is going to be 150Mbps and a lot of short bursts across the network followed by long waits.

Comment: When dealing with variables and flexible standards and other things, the rule of thumb is to do an estimate of needs and then buy the best equipment you can afford, taking those estimates into consideration.

Comment: @music2myear thank you for your comment. That is definitely true, but "best you can afford" is sometimes a bit blurry. I **could** splurge with > € 600 for a new Wifi 6E triband mesh network, but it just doesn't make sense given the circumstances...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've heard many times that what I want is not posisble due to the many factors of uncertainty:

- number of devices
- peak bandwidth requirements
- distance to access points
- physical obstacles
- ...

I stumbled across this incredibly detailed page that covers pretty much everything about Wifi standards and realistic expectations based on many different Wifi characteristics and features:

https://www.duckware.com/tech/wifi-in-the-us.html#routers

> **2401 Mbps speed**: The 2401 Mbps maximum PHY speed is for an 80 MHz channel to an 4×4 client. *However, a much more realistic maximum PHY speed is 1200 Mbps for an 80 MHz channel to a 2×2 client (840 Mbps throughput)*, and for a realistic distance away from the router, a PHY speed of 864 Mbps (600 Mbps throughput).

This provides clear guidance that e.g. Wifi AX3000 (600 Mbps in the 2.4 GHz band and 2400 Mbps in the 5 GHz band) would only get me 600 Mbps throughput in realistics conditions.
AX1800 provides only half of that, ending up with about 300 Mbps throughput. That is close to the current 260 Mbps that I get from my current Wifi 5 router.

This would conclude (for my case) that AX1800 will date too quickly and AX3000 is favorable over AX1800 to be future proof. So (refering to the [ref closed post](https://superuser.com/questions/1738533/should-i-invest-in-wifi-6-mesh-ax1800-or-ax3000)) this would mean that AX3000 is the way to go to be future proof.

**Edit**: but I do realize that getting 260 Mbps is more than I need for four people (2 adults, 2 children 9-11yo) to actually consume. So for now and even for the forseeable future, the AX1800 might suffice.

**Edit 2**: additionally, as this will be in a mesh configuration, half of the bandwidth of the 2nd sattelite will be reserved for WiFi backhaul, hence slashing the AX3000 to AX1800 speeds anyway without an Ethernet backhaul. In case of the AX1800 this would be half of that 300 Mbps if connected to the sattelite only, hence delivering only 150 Mbps. **That** is the most important reason not to go for the AX1800 Wifi, unless there is an Ethernet backhaul. And in these lower speed ends, we are typically facing cheaper models that don't offer Ethernet backhaul.

Comment: An extra interesting link to read is [this one by DongKnows](https://dongknows.com/mesh-wi-fi-system-explained/) (he sure seems to).

Answer (score 0):

Mokubai is correct, you simply cannot divide or calculate in this case, the amount of bandwidth a device  is going to use, it depends on how powerful the device is (i.e., a PS5 running on its 5ghz connection over WiFi, or its Ethernet port).

You can however, limit the bandwidth a device can receive by simply logging in to your gateway, then placing limitations to, e.g., 7.5-10mbps which will in turn free up quite a bit of bandwidth available for those powerful devices you own.

From my experience, I used to limit the bandwidth of my PS4 Pro at an old address I used to live in before fiber connections were introduced in Australia, also known as the No Broadband Network (our fiber is trash), to 2mbps.... Yeah..... welcome to ADSL2+, to allow more bandwidth for my PC, i.e., I had to switch off most of my devices to free up enough bandwidth.

Godspeed, I hope this helps :).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there has to be a better answer than this, right? I mean, it's just trial and error? I got a 260Mbps line (whch I'm happy with) and I can choose between 1800Mbps or 3000Mbps Wifi e.g. Both would theoretically suffice, but will they in practice with 13 devices, 4 of which may present serious bandwidth requirements, but always limiting to 260Mbps. I'm of course also trying to future proof for the day that my ISP bandwidth will be 500Mbps or maybe even 1Gbps, then my 1800 Mbps or 3000 Mbps wifi should still provide the actual ISP bandwidth, divided by the users.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Check out my answer, that was what I was going for. 1800 Mbps theoretically comes down to about 300 Mbps (including signal loss, interference and whatnot) and in mesh networks could down even more due to wireless backhaul.